# How to open all tweet links in a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter

Does anybody know how to open all my tweet links in a new window?
I need this to be done in [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Autodealers/XSmYa/).

Thank you in advanced!
With Kind Regards,
Jonathan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/XSmYa/18/

use the jquery find function to do the following

```
$('#timeline').append(timeline).find("a").attr('target', '_blank');
```

Comment: Thank you! This will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this approach - it overrides the link click event to open a new window or tab.

```
$('#timeline').delegate("a", "click", function(){
    window.open($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

This can be done independently from the script generating the content.

Comment: dont most browsers detect this as a popup and block it?  Ive not had great success with window.open for external links in the past.

Comment: +1 though for making it futureproof with the delegate function.  That is one definite advantage, as any `a` element that gets added, at any time, will now use this behavior.

Comment: This should be fine because the user manually clicks the link.  It's when you start opening windows with this method automatically that the browsers get upset about it.  I prefer it as a more "unobtrusive" approach - the HTML stays a bit more semantic.

Comment: Thnx for your reply, but I'll go for Kirean's answer.